# Java Mulithreaded CopyONWriteArrayList

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to use data structure which can be constantly accesed by multithreaded code . Please let me know any Data structure in java , where I can wait and use notify options . Kindly see the below code , why run method of CDRemove doesnot print all values

```
public class ConcurrencyDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        CopyOnWriteArrayList<String> threadSafeList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<String>();
        CDInsert cd1 = new CDInsert(threadSafeList);
        CDRemove cr1 = new CDRemove(threadSafeList);
        cd1.start();

        cr1.start();
    }
}

class CDInsert extends Thread
{
    List threadSafeList;

    public CDInsert(List threadSafeList) {
         this.threadSafeList = threadSafeList;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        int counter = 0;
        while(counter < 20){
            counter++;
            threadSafeList.add(String.valueOf(counter));
            System.out.println("Counter value is "+counter);
        }
    }

    public void showItem(){
        Iterator<String> failSafeIterator = threadSafeList.iterator();
        while(failSafeIterator.hasNext()){
            System.out.printf("Read from CopyOnWriteArrayList : %s %n", failSafeIterator.next());
        }
    }
}

class CDRemove extends Thread {
    List threadSafeList;

    public CDRemove(List threadSafeList) {
        this.threadSafeList = threadSafeList;
    }

    public void run(){

        Iterator<String> failSafeIterator = threadSafeList.iterator();
        System.out.println("Fail Safe Iterator is "+failSafeIterator);
        while(true){
            System.out.println("Fail Safe Iterator is "+failSafeIterator);  
            while(failSafeIterator.hasNext()){
                System.out.printf("Read from CopyOnWriteArrayList : %s %n", failSafeIterator.next());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should display all the items? What's your reasoning?

Comment: CopyOnWrite is not exactly a cheap option. java.util.concurrent makes some things easier but one still needs to understand threading and synchronization. It makes a fresh copy the data with each modification

Answer (score 1):

thread CDRemove has an infinite loop:

```
 while(true){ // Change this.
     while(failSafeIterator.hasNext()){
        System.out.printf("Read from CopyOnWriteArrayList : %s %n", failSafeIterator.next());
    }
    }
```

Now the iterator will represent the state of the list when constructed. If the CDInsert thread was still running, the iterator would not have all the elements.